# Android best practice to save images temporarily and remove them when no longer?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I am currently developing an android app. In this app, I download images from remote server in order to show them in it. Actually, I save these files in sdcard/emulated/0/myapp. What I need is how to make these images temporarily available when the user uses myapp and they should be removed as the user closed the app following best practices in this issue. My code to save images into sdcard is:

```
public static String saveToSdCard(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {

    String stored = null;

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File folder = new File(sdcard.getAbsoluteFile(), "myapp");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile(), filename + ".jpeg");
    if(file.exists()){
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*if (file.exists())
        return stored;
    */
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        stored = "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stored;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you use Picasso caching capabilities? Haven't using them extensively myself, but from what I've read they're quite good. Try this link -> https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-influencing-image-caching

Comment: Does Picasso have functions to save downloaded images in somewhere in order to access them later during exploring the app. for example in activity A I use image a.png and I moved to other activities and returned back to the activity A does Picasso download it again or use it. If so this issue may consume my bandwidth.

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki thank you so much. it seems the solution I search for. I will try to use and write back here.

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki I used Picasso api and it fulfilled my requirements. thanks again.

Comment: can you please mark my answer as the correct one? I'm trying to gain more point on SO. Thanks in advance. KK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use Picasso caching capabilities? Try this link -> https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-influencing-image-caching

Answer (score 1):

Store them in cache directory. Cache Directory found by getCacheDir() function.

Comment: This could be a way but you have to remember to clear the cache on exit to delete the files. Android deletes files in the cache only if it's in a memory space shortage. Doc here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#InternalCache